# Organizing data by month in grafana using psql

Tags: sql, postgresql, grafana

so im trying to create a Bar gauge dashboard and i have my code right the only problem is that the results given are by Month Name and in the dashboard it is not organized in the right order instead the results are organized in alphabetical order and i wanted them to be organized by months ir cronological order (normal order like 1, 2, 3, ...)

This is my code:

```
SELECT NOW() as time, TO_CHAR(updated_on, 'Month'), SUM(time_spent_minutes)/COUNT(DISTINCT ticket_id) "Avg"
FROM ticket_messages
WHERE 
    admin_id IN ('20439', '20457', '20291', '20371', '20357', '20235','20449','20355','20488') and
    (updated_on BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL '1 YEAR' AND NOW())
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(updated_on, 'Month')
ORDER BY 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Order by the integer value of month

```
SELECT NOW() as time, TO_CHAR(updated_on, 'Month'), SUM(time_spent_minutes)/COUNT(DISTINCT ticket_id) "Avg"
FROM ticket_messages
WHERE 
    admin_id IN ('20439', '20457', '20291', '20371', '20357', '20235','20449','20355','20488') and
    (updated_on BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL '1 YEAR' AND NOW())
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(updated_on, 'Month')
ORDER BY TO_CHAR(updated_on, 'mm')::integer
```

Comment: Im thankfull for your time trying to help me, but that dosnt work for this, because it makes me put the updated_on on "GROUP BY" and doing that it screw my code.

Comment: I got the code right now but the problem is that grafana doesnt organize the data properly, in the "Pg Admin 3" it shows me the data just like i want but when using grafana it doesnt work like that.

Comment: Add month number to your fields in select statement then use it to order in your dashboards.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    to_char(now(), 'YYYY-MM'),
    to_char(now(), 'YYYY-Mon'),
    to_char(now(), 'YYYY-mon'),
    to_char(now(), 'YYYY-MON'),
    to_char(now(), 'YYYY-MON'),
    to_char(now(), 'YYY-MON'),
    to_char(now(), 'Y,YYY-MON');
```

source:   https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html